# State isn't Updated in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm developing in react native from last month and I have done a project for practice, I have some issues with it, when I Login and setState to update my state it's not being updated with sample username and password for testing.

ScreenShots about an issue:
   [image: Login Screen]

[image: Input Component]

This is my Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput } from "react-native";

import Button from "./common/Button";
import Card from "./common/Card";
import CardItem from "./common/CardItem";
import Input from "./common/Input";

class Login extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { username: "anas", password: "123" };
      }

      handleLogin = () => {
           console.log(
                   `Email is: ${this.state.username} and pass is: ${this.state.password} .`
            );
      };
      render() {
           return (
             <View>
                <Card>
                   <CardItem>
                       <Input
                          label="Email: "
                          placeholder="Enter your Email.."
                          secureTextEntry={false}
                          onChangeText={username => this.setState({ 
                          username})}
                        />
                 </CardItem>
                 <CardItem>
                      <Input
                       label="Password: "
                       placeholder="Enter your password.."
                       secureTextEntry={true}
                       onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password})}
                      />
                 </CardItem>
                 <CardItem>
                    <Button btnTitle="Login" onPressHandle={this.handleLogin} 
                    />
                 </CardItem>
             <Text>Email: {this.state.username}</Text>
             <Text>pass: {this.state.password}</Text>
          </Card>
      </View>
    );
   }
 }
 export default Login;
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: I need when I enter a username and pass updated the state with the new value

Comment: I see you have already done this. you can use this.state.username to access the username after input is given

Comment: How is your `Input` component? Your code works with `TextInput` component from `react-native`.

Comment: I just separate the component in other files and import them in my parent file, when I use TextInput from 'react-native' it's work fine, but when I use my Input component it does not work well?

Comment: @devserkan  check my updated Q to see my input component

Comment: @mostafizrahman in genral it's work but when i use my custom Input component it's not work fine

Comment: For the next time, just try to share the code here, not the images :) We can't use images to get your code easily.

Comment: @devserkan, In General, thank you firstly, I know it's Wrong to share Image here anyway I don't will do in future

Comment: You are welcome and thank you for your understanding of the images issue. You and we will both benefit about this in the future. We can play with your code easily and you will get faster answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `onChangeText` prop in your custom `Input` component, so add it.

```
<TextInput
    ...other props
    onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
/>
```

Comment: That is a great catch! I missed the pic completely!

Comment: Thank you @Wainage.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks :)